# How to redirect only the Home Page of a Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to know how to redirect *ONLY* the Home Page of a **Wordpress** site
to another domain.

Read a few other posts on this but none of them work.

This is what I've tried in my `.htaccess`:

```
 RedirectMatch ^/$ http://newsite.com
```

However *ALL* the pages on my site are being redirected to the new site.

Anyone have any ideas on what else to try?

Thanks.

Comment: Inside an `init` function in your theme, you could do a redirect using something like `if (is_home() || is_front()) {header('location:www.myurl.com');}`

Comment: Here's a solution I found by a quick Google search: http://serverfault.com/questions/58762/how-to-redirect-root-and-only-root-via-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Your URL will never reach `/` it is always redirected to the domain without the trailing slash. While PHP will interpret the root of the domain as `/`, the REQUEST_URI from Apache is actually looking for an empty string. This can be written as `^$`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$  http://newsite.com [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this causes a page like this  http://oldsite.com/?page_id=286 to be redirected to http://newsite.com/?page_id=286 so same problem as before

Comment: in the above case I need it to stay with the oldsite only for the home page. I also seem to have this problem if I try to redirect index.html to the new site, this was from an even older version of the site

Answer (score 0):

Just place this rule as very first rule in your WP .htaccess file:

```
%{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[\s?#]
RewriteRule ^$ http://newsite.com [L,R=301]
```